# Cloudfront EC2 Configuration working only for Root URL

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured an EC2 instance with Cloudfront to use SSL(from ACM).

It works fine only for the root URL (example.com) but not for other URLs (example.com/page1).

**502 Error : The request could not be satisfied.**

[image: 502 Error : The request could not be satisfied.]

[image: Response Headers]

Comment: There's not enough information, here.  How many Cache Behaviors have you configured?  Just one, or more than one?  What are the response headers you see from this request, specifically, is there an `Age:` header?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Question edited. Only the default cache behavior.

Comment: What protocol does CloudFront use for connection with the Origin? https, http or match-viewer?

Comment: It's https. The webserver is [keystonejs](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone)